# Could not open database ''

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a database with tables mapped to z:/... Z is a virtual drive on my computer, it is actually a folder in my C drive. I'm trying to run code but I keep getting the following error after a few hours of the code running.

> Could not open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

The code runs queries via `DoCmd` that delete records and insert into a table repeatedly in a loop. The last time the error occurred was in loop 59. The database in Z drive gives me a warning when I try to open it, but it opens and seems fine.

When I try to run a query in query design, I get

> Unrecognized database format 'path-to/my-database.accdb'

Why does this keep happening?

Comment: You are creating, but not closing some recordsets? Older MSJet/Access engine does go mad after 400 recordsets are left opened.

Comment: @Arvo, Nope. I am opening a recordset inside the loop ,but I close it inside as well.

Comment: My guess is after a couple hours of running, you run into the Access 2GB limit

Comment: @random_answer_guy, what does that mean? Limit where?

Comment: Total size for an Access database (.accdb), including all database objects and data is 2 gigabytes, minus the space needed for system objects.

Comment: @random_answer_guy, That could be. But I took out the `INSERT` from my code, and left only the `DELETE`. Deleting records couldn't have *increased* the database size, could it?

Comment: Deletions don't shrink your db, until you `compact` your db. Show your code!